# Composition of Differential Operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

If I have:

$A=\partial_x^2+u(x)$

$B=u(x)\partial_x$

How do I compose: $AB$ and $BA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just usual composition of functions: for all $f$ in an appropriate domain
$(AB)(f)=A(B(f))=(\partial^2_x+u)(u\partial_x f)=\partial^2_x (u\partial_x f)+u^2\partial_x f=\cdots$ using the chain rule, and similarily for $BA$. Notice that $u$ acts as a multiplication operator. Apart from that, *it is totally crucial for composition that you specify both domain and codomain of $A$ and $B$* and in particular what is assumed about $u$ (say domain and codomain is $C^\infty$, and $u$ be also of class $C^\infty$).

Comment: When you mean that $u$ acts as a multiplication factor, does it mean that I don't have to differentiate it?

Comment: you have to differentiate it where I wrote $\cdots$, but you see it makes no sense to write $u(u\partial_x f)$ as $u$ is defined on some subset of, say, $\mathbf{R}^n$ whereas $u\partial_x f$ is a function (not an element of the domain of $u$). The best you can do is multiply, $(u^2\partial_x f)(x)=u(x)(u\partial_x f)(x)$. $u$ can also be considered as an operator: if $f\in C^\infty$ define $(uf)(x):=u(x)f(x)$.

Comment: Of course we assume here that we can actually multiply, that all $u$ and $f$ take values in $\mathbf{C}$ or $\mathbf{R}$ but that goes without saying.